# Hostgroup 0 has no servers available! Checking servers shunned > for more than 1 second, ProxySQL

Tags: mysql, database, proxysql

I was getting the above error, so, i was checking proxy logs. I found that every 3 failed logins, proxy shunned for 10 seconds. Is this behavior normal? Any work around from preventing from getting shunned?

> 2023-07-27 08:57:33 mysql_connection.cpp:969:handler(): [ERROR] Failed
> to mysql_real_connect() on "IP":3306 , FD (Conn:99 , MyDS:99) , 1862:
> Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a client
> that supports expired passwords.. 2023-07-27 08:57:33
> mysql_connection.cpp:969:handler(): [ERROR] Failed to
> mysql_real_connect() on "IP":3306 , FD (Conn:99 , MyDS:99) , 1862:
> Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a client
> that supports expired passwords.. 2023-07-27 08:57:33
> mysql_connection.cpp:969:handler(): [ERROR] Failed to
> mysql_real_connect() on "IP":3306 , FD (Conn:99 , MyDS:99) , 1862:
> Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a client
> that supports expired passwords.. 2023-07-27 08:57:33
> MySQL_HostGroups_Manager.cpp:906:connect_error(): [ERROR] Shunning
> server "IP":3306 with 5 errors/sec. Shunning for 10 seconds 2023-07-27
> 08:57:33 MySQL_HostGroups_Manager.cpp:2446:get_random_MySrvC():
> [ERROR] Hostgroup 0 has no servers available! Checking servers shunned
> for more than 1 second 2023-07-27 08:57:35
> MySQL_HostGroups_Manager.cpp:2446:get_random_MySrvC(): [ERROR]
> Hostgroup 0 has no servers available! Checking servers shunned for
> more than 1 second 2023-07-27 08:57:35
> mysql_connection.cpp:969:handler(): [ERROR] Failed to
> mysql_real_connect() on "IP":3306 , FD (Conn:99 , MyDS:99) , 1862:
> Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a client
> that supports expired passwords.. 2023-07-27 08:57:35
> mysql_connection.cpp:969:handler(): [ERROR] Failed to
> mysql_real_connect() on "IP":3306 , FD (Conn:99 , MyDS:99) , 1862:
> Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a client
> that supports expired passwords.. 2023-07-27 08:57:35
> mysql_connection.cpp:969:handler(): [ERROR] Failed to
> mysql_real_connect() on "IP":3306 , FD (Conn:99 , MyDS:99) , 1862:
> Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a client
> that supports expired passwords.. 2023-07-27 08:57:35
> MySQL_HostGroups_Manager.cpp:906:connect_error(): [ERROR] Shunning
> server "IP":3306 with 5 errors/sec. Shunning for 10 seconds 2023-07-27
> 08:57:37 MySQL_HostGroups_Manager.cpp:2446:get_random_MySrvC():
> [ERROR] Hostgroup 0 has no servers available! Checking servers shunned
> for more than 1 second 2023-07-27 08:57:37
> mysql_connection.cpp:969:handler(): [ERROR] Failed to
> mysql_real_connect() on "IP":3306 , FD (Conn:99 , MyDS:99) , 1862:
> Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a client
> that supports expired passwords.. 2023-07-27 08:57:37
> mysql_connection.cpp:969:handler(): [ERROR] Failed to
> mysql_real_connect() on 10.109.32.152:3306 , FD (Conn:99 , MyDS:99) ,
> 1862: Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a
> client that supports expired passwords.. 2023-07-27 08:57:37
> mysql_connection.cpp:969:handler(): [ERROR] Failed to
> mysql_real_connect() on "IP":3306 , FD (Conn:99 , MyDS:99) , 1862:
> Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a client
> that supports expired passwords.. 2023-07-27 08:57:37
> MySQL_HostGroups_Manager.cpp:906:connect_error(): [ERROR] Shunning
> server "IP":3306 with 5 errors/sec. Shunning for 10 seconds 2023-07-27
> 08:57:39 MySQL_HostGroups_Manager.cpp:2446:get_random_MySrvC():
> [ERROR] Hostgroup 0 has no servers available! Checking servers shunned
> for more than 1 second